# numba.core.errors.TypingError: while using np.random.randint()

Tags: python, numpy, numba

How to use `np.random.randint` with numba as this throws a very large error, https://hastebin.com/kodixazewo.sql

```py
from numba import jit
import numpy as np
@jit(nopython=True)
def foo():
    a = np.random.randint(16, size=(3,3))
    return a
foo()
```

Comment: Only the first 2 arguments of [numpy.random.randint](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/reference/numpysupported.html?highlight=random) are supported

Comment: @Oluwafemi Sule is correct and I vote for him :-) - the arguments are `low` and `high`. I also added a minimal work around in the answers

Comment: Incidentally the hastebin link is broken for me already

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `np.ndindex` to loop over your desired output size and call `np.random.randint` for each element individually.

Make sure the output datatype is sufficient to support the range of integers from the randint call.

```
from numba import njit
import numpy as np

@njit
def foo(size=(3,3)):
    
    out = np.empty(size, dtype=np.uint16)
        
    for idx in np.ndindex(size): 
        out[idx] = np.random.randint(16)
        
    return out
```

This makes it work for any arbitrary shape:

```
foo(size=(2,2,2))
```

Results in:

```
array([[[ 8,  7],
        [15,  2]],

       [[ 4, 13],
        [ 5, 11]]], dtype=uint16)
```

Answer (score 0):

see [here](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/user/5minguide.html#what-is-nopython-mode) for more detail regarding the `nopython` var.

```
from numba import jit
import numpy as np
import warnings

warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")  # suppress NumbaWarning - remove and read for more info
@jit(nopython=False)   # I guess we need the Python interpreter to randomize with more than 2 parameters in np.random.randint()        
def foo():
    a = np.random.randint(16, size=(3,3))
    return a
foo()
```

Comment: I am using this in a function that requires `nopython=True`